# Firebase cloud function (called from firebase ios sdk) error: FirebaseAuthError: Firebase ID token has expired

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have cloud functions in my firebase project:
[image]

I call these functions from Android and iOS firebase SDK. As you see they allow unauthenticated users.
No problem with Android but on iOS some users get this error (I see it in cloud functions log):

*Failed to validate auth token. FirebaseAuthError: Firebase ID token has expired. Get a fresh ID token from your client app and try again (auth/id-token-expired). See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token*

I call cloud functions using this simple helper class:

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseFunctions

public class CloudFunctionExecutor {
    public static let REGION = "europe-west2";
    lazy var functions = Functions.functions(region : CloudFunctionExecutor.REGION)
    
    public func callFunctionResult(_ functionName : String, _ data : [String : Any], _ onResult : @escaping ([String : Any]?) -> () ) {
         functions.httpsCallable(functionName).call(data) { (result, error) in
             ...
        }
    }
}
```

I don't generate/refresh any tokens.
Some of this cloud functions are called on application start and they do not require the user to be logged in.
I don't know if it matters but I call Auth.auth().signInAnonymously() later when user click on some menu button

I can't reproduce this error on my device but the problem is probably connected with wrong date/time on the mobile.

This problem does not appear on Android. On iOS only less than 1% users are affected.
I did't find any solution on: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

So my question is how to get rid of this error even when user has wrong time on his device?